# requiredif data annotation does not work client side with file uploads

Tags: javascript, c#, validation

I am using expressive.annotations.validate.js to validate on the client side, however it does not work with file upload, specially the requiredif one.

I used requiredif to say that the file upload is required unless a check box is checked, but enforcing the requirement client side.

I expect the required to be enforced client side unless the checkbox is checked.

Here is the Code I am using:

public bool? IsEligible { get; set; }

```
    [Display(Name = "Choose Files")]
    [RequiredIf("IsEligible", true, ErrorMessage = "Documentation is required. Supported File Formats: PDF, PNG, JPG, and JPEG, of size under 5 MB.")]
    [NotMapped]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [FileType("PDF,JPG,JPEG,PNG,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png", ErrorMessage = "Please select only Supported Files PDF, PNG, JPG, and JPEG, of size under 5 MB.")]
    [FileSize(5000000, ErrorMessage = "Please select a file under 5 MB")]
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> DocumentationFiles { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.